# How can I use a deep default configuration in symfony

Tags: symfony, configuration

I am trying to create a bundle that wont require a config file, but default values do not work.

Here is the code:

```
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder('acme_newsletter');

        $treeBuilder->getRootNode()
            ->children()
                ->arrayNode('security')
                    ->children()
                        ->scalarNode('foo_key')->defaultValue('%env(FOO_KEY)%')->end()
                        ->scalarNode('bar_key')->defaultValue('%env(BAR_KEY)%')->end()
                        ->scalarNode('baz_key')->defaultValue('%env(BAZ_KEY)%')->end()
                    ->end()
                ->end()
            ->end();

        return $treeBuilder;
    }
```

Now when I use this file Symfony wont use the default values unless I create at least following config file:

```
acme_newsletter:
   security:
```

Is there a way to use default values without requiring any files to be created?

edit:

I did load the configuration in the extension class:

```
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);
        $container->setParameter('acme_newsletter.config', $config);

        $loader = new YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__ . '/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.yaml');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it is possible to create default config. 
According to this [article](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/configuration.html)

You should load Configuration class, in configuration extension as follow:

```
// src/Acme/SocialBundle/DependencyInjection/AcmeSocialExtension.php
public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $configuration = new Configuration();
    $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);
}
```

Remember that 'new **Configuration**()' is your bundle class with config tree.
This custom class can be used in your load() method to merge configurations.

If you want to prepare default values (and there is no any config file) use method from arrayNode() 
Example:

```
$rootNode
->arrayNode('children_one')
  ->addDefaultsIfNotSet() <- call this before children()
  ->children()
    ->integerNode('children_one_one')
       ->defaultValue(1)
    ->end()
  ->end()
->end()
```

Comment: That is exactly what I did (I just didn't write all the obvious stuff).
The problem is that it does not load the default values unless you create the empty-ish config file in the project.

Comment: @HubertNNN Take a look at edited answer, I tested it and it works fine. Let me know if it helps you.